# Rails 4, Devise associate users to post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I have Devise setup and can create posts, but I would like to add the username of the creator of the post.
Am I missing something?

posts controller:

```
def create
@post = current_member.posts.new(params[:post])


@post = Post.new(post_params)
respond_to do |format|
  if @post.save
    format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @post }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

post model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :member
end
```

member model: (I'm using member as user)

```
  class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
    has_many :posts

end
```

In show.html I don't know what to put on the buttom to display the username. I get errors or it will just display the current user email on all post until i log out, then nil error of course.

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

 <p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @post.title %>
      </p>

  <p>
      <strong>Author:</strong>
      <%= @post.author %>
    </p>

     <p>
       <strong>Main:</strong>
     <%= @post.main %>
        </p>

           <%= current_member.email %>
          <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %> |
            <%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you don't want the logged-in member/user's e-mail with the post but instead the author's e-mail. Try: `@post.member.email`